# Ambiguous error between TableNameAttribute.TableNameAttribute(string)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just upgraded the `.Net v4.0` to `4.6.1` and ended up having the ambiguous error for the sql related attributes(TableName, PrimaryKey, Column) I used in the application.

I am trying to figure out which DLL is causing this error.I am seeing the errors like

1. TableNameAttribute.TableNameAttribute(string)
2. PrimaryKey.
3. ColumnAttribute...etc

I want to know which `dll` I have to delete

Comment: The error message should tell among which DLLs this is ambiguous? Can you share that message too?

Comment: CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'TableNameAttribute.TableNameAttribute(string)' and 'TableNameAttribute.TableNameAttribute(string)'

Comment: This is the error I am getting

Comment: Can you share the code too with pointing out the line which is showing the error?

Comment: [TableName("ActivityType")]
[PrimaryKey("ActivityTypeId", AutoIncrement = false)]
[ExplicitColumns]
public partial class ActivityTypeEntity 
   {...}

Comment: through out the application I am getting this type of error in models wherever there is an sql related attributes

Answer (score 0):

the ambiguity was between the Entity framework and the System.componentmodel.dataannotations